# NTLM Auth on Newman

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

I have a collection of requests exported to Postman
I need to run these tests with Newman, but I can't find anything about authentication. The authentication I use is NTLM and I need to add this authentication to the command, are there any ways to do this with programs like node etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

NTLM is supported in the authorization tab.

Comment: i tried i know that but when i run the command adding the env variable i still got 401

Comment: did you try it from UI and see if its passing first before using newman ?

Comment: yes i got a little bug, when i open postman for the first time and run the test i got 401, when i send a single request and after i send it i run the test the test run without problem, i dont knwo why this issue

Comment: make sure you have saved your request and the authentication is there for the first request in your test run or in collection pre-requisit

Comment: after the first request the session is cached (This is windows behavior ) then if you want to reauthenticate again then you have to send a request without the header connection: keep-alive ,

Comment: i will try it, i let it know if i solveed it ok ?

Comment: sure let me know

Comment: Hey i tried to lunch a pre-req script sending a random request from my collection same issue still 401

Comment: You have to do authentication in prerequest script , try creating a new request instead of sending request from script

Comment: but i found a solution maybe a little bit bad but it work, for each  request i do the auth in the single request. for your solution i doont have in mind in which sense i need to create a request if you can provide an example i would try, Thanks

Comment: in the pre-re i set the env variable and i send a reuqets but for creating i dont know how to do it